# Why didn't the first years know about the Sorting ceremony?

Tags: harry-potter

In the first book, *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*, just before the Sorting ceremony, all the first years were quite terrified. No one had any idea what was going to follow (even Ron who came from a wizarding family). Why is this?

The ceremony itself is not a secret since most of the wizards in England went through it. Even if there is an unofficial rule not to talk about it, at least some of the kids would probably have heard about it and spread the news.

Comment: I guess maybe it was not relevant enough to bring up at home. Maybe it was not that interesting enough to talk about. They also probably referred to it as 'sorting' and listeners may not have though much of it as a ceremony. These kids would also be in a strange magical castle with ghosts running around and at a new school. I would probably be terrified as well.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - I assumed it was a typo :-)

Comment: Many things like this are hazing rituals.  There are many analogues in the real world, particularly for organizations like college fraternities/sororities.  For example, I work for Georgia Tech, and it's common to talk to freshmen about the accomplishments of [George P. Burdell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_P._Burdell) as if he were real, even though everyone on campus knows it's a joke.

Comment: Didn't Harry tell his son at the end of the Deathly Hallows about the sorting hat?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ron *has* heard about it, it's just that his brothers have taken great time and care to tell him a load of rubbish in order to scare him, one assumes for their own amusement :

> *‘How exactly do they sort us into houses?’ he asked Ron.*
>
> *‘Some sort of test, I think. Fred said it hurts a lot, but I think he
> was joking.’*
>
> ...
>
> *‘So we’ve just got to try on the hat!’ Ron whispered to Harry. **‘I’ll kill Fred, he was going on about wrestling a troll.’***
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*</sup></sub>

Within the book, the only character we see who actually seems clueless about the ceremony (aside from our hero, who's been raised by Muggles) is Hermione, who's been raised by Muggles. The others just seem nervous/terrified in general terms.

---

With regard to what first years know in general, certainly the *Sorting Hat* is expecting that the first years will be aware of its purpose, although this may be because McGonagall (or whoever filled her role for the previous thousand years) is expected to explain it to them before they walk in:

> ***And now the Sorting Hat is here
>
> And you all know the score
>
> I sort you into houses
>
> Because that is what I’m for***
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*</sup></sub>

And when Harry's son goes to school in the final book, it seems that he has told him about the ceremony *in general terms*, but without offering any specifics about the sorting itself or the choice that the Hat makes. The implication being that the Sorting is something of a rite of passage that the parents don't wish to spoil:

> *'...But if it matters to you, you’ll be able to choose Gryffindor over Slytherin. The Sorting Hat takes your choice into account.’
>
> ‘Really?’
>
> ‘It did for me,’ said Harry.
>
> **He had never told any of his children that before***
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*</sup></sub>

Comment: -1 for using that atrocious epilogue as support for an otherwise good story.  (Kidding.  About the downvote, at least.)

Comment: @asteri: I remember being really disappointed by the epilogue.  I remember having on Ms. Rowling's web site, before the publication of book 6 IIRC, that Ms. Rowling had the last chapter of the last book in a safe somewhere [or something to that effect]; I think she said that to indicate she knew where the overall story was going, but the epilogue didn't seem to have much to do with the events of the main story beyond the naming of Harry's children.

Comment: @supercat Pretty sure there are quotes from Rowling herself saying she screwed up the epilogue.  I know she at least blatantly admitted that [the Hermione-Ron thing was completely wrong](http://www.cnn.com/2014/02/02/showbiz/rowling-hermione-ron-revelation/).

Comment: @asteri - I'm 99% certain that she said those things in order to gain additional publicity for her Pottermore site, rather than because she genuinely thinks them.

Comment: Nice analysis but I still find it very unlikely that no one know what exactly expects them :) For example Hermione mentions that she did already read "Hogarts: A History" and I find it very unlikely that the sorting hat is not mentioned there.

Comment: @vap78 - Which certainly raises a few questions. Presumably the hat isn't mentioned in the book, which beggars the question "why not?". Unanswerable, I'm afraid.

Comment: @asteri: Even though I didn't like the epilogue, I like the idea of Harry+Ginny and Ron+Hermione pairings better than Harry+Hermione.  The idea of the sorting hat remaining mysterious to those who have never used it, however, seems reasonable.  Thinking about it, a notion I don't think Ms. Rowling used in her books but would fit with the animated-portrait concept, would be that books [e.g. 'Hogwarts: A History'] could have some magical intelligence of their own that could hide "spoilers" from people who shouldn't see them.

Comment: @vap78 Agreed. The fact that she would be worried about what spell to use when she knew all about the ceiling of the Great Hall from 'Hogwarts, A History'! It's ridiculous. :(

Comment: @petra_delphiki - I suspect it's because the sorting ceremony is supposed to be a pleasant surprise for new students and part of the school's mystique.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I agree with this theory, but it may help.

The video is from Super Carlin Brothers, a really great youtube channel.

If you do not want to watch the full video, here is a quick summary: Ben says he believes it is the Fidelius Charm. He then encounters the problem of who is Secret-Keeper. As Hogwarts has been around for a thousand years, then the Secret-Keeper would have died. He explains his further research and then concludes that the Hat is its own Secret-Keeper. Watch the video for more details.

Comment: link-only answers are to be avoided. If the video dies (as they often do on Youtube) then your answer becomes worthless. Perhaps you could provide a transcript of the important bit/s for those who don't want to watch all 11 minutes

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the parents or the elders want it to be random. The Hat gets the thought of mind and on the basis of their ability it selects the house. So elders want their children go to their house based on their ability. Not which one they want, it can be possible for the children to change their thoughts and go into the tough house, which they are not related to.