# How come Ron knew nothing about the Sorting Hat?

Tags: harry-potter, sorting-hat

In *Harry Potter and Philosopher Stone* Ron is oblivious about the sorting ceremony same as everyone else.

> "How exactly do they sort us into Houses?" he asked Ron. 
>   "Some sort of test I think. Fred said it hurts a lot, but I think he was joking."

While it is understandable that Fred and George would lie to make a good laugh, Ron got the whole bunch of other family members who would have passed the sorting ceremony before - including three elder brothers and his parents. Ron definitely knew about different houses in the school and that he'd probably end up in Griffindor as the rest of his family. Have they never ever discussed the sorting in their family? Have he never bothered to ask (anyone except Fred) of such an important part of being accepted to the school? It's just unbelievable.
Especially after we see Ron was actually interested in the matter as he was scared by Fred's interpretation:

> "So we've just got to try on the hat!"- Ron whispered to Harry.
>   "I'll kill Fred, he was going on about wrestling a troll."

Hermione seems not to know either:

> No one was talking much except Hermione Granger, who was whispering very fast about all the spells she'd learned and wondering which one she'd need.

That implies that information about the Sorting Hat is not in the *Hogwarts, A History* - and it's also a very strange omission for such a book.

We could assume it's some sort of a secret and those who were accepted to Hogwarts bound not to tell others, but in *Harry Potter and Deathly Hallows* Albus seems to know about the Hat already:

> ..."But if it matters to you, you'll be able to choose Griffindoe over Slytherin. The Sorting Hat takes your choice into account." - "Really?" - "It did for me," - said Harry.

Comment: Related, if not dupe: [Why didn't the first years know about the Sorting ceremony?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/79497/98028) to which the accepted answer quoted the line following your last quote and explaining it with _"The implication being that the Sorting is something of a rite of passage that the parents don't wish to spoil"_

Comment: @Jenayah damn, you're right, I looked for a dupe first, but haven't found that one. I would not have accepted the answer there though... I still find it unlikely the whole Weasley family would do such a big secret of it for the sake of "surprise". I mean, it's a bit of a job to make sorting ceremony discussions a total taboo in such a big family.

Comment: No problem, there are literally thousands of HP questions, hard to find the right set of keywords. as per keeping stuff secret in the Weasley family I remember Ginny sneakily practicing Quidditch so y'know... It can be done I guess.

Comment: Also if you look at the succession of siblings: Charlie may not tell Bill because parents told him not to and they agree, same for Bill/Percy, Percy doesn't tell the twins because he's a jerk, twins don't tell Ron because they're jokers, Ron doesn't tell Ginny because retaliation/tradition

Comment: @Jenayah Switch Bill and Charlie.